# How to read the value of Progress View?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, uiprogressview

For filling the Progress Bar, there're 2 objects connected to ViewController.swift file.

```
@IBOutlet var progBar: UIProgressView!

@IBAction func butPressed(sender: UIButton) {
self.progBar.progress += 0.1
```

But when I try to read the value of the bar has with the way below, nothing happens. Except the following message :

`value <UIProgressView: 0x7ff85bd9eb00; frame = (85 128; 146 2); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ff85bd9ee70>>`

```
println ("The value is \(progBar)")
```

How to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIProgressView has a property called progress which is a float between 0 and 1.  If you are wanting to print it, you just need to access it instead of the whole view.

```
println("The value is \(progBar.progress)")
```

You do not need to create another variable to hold this information.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep a variable to store the value of the progress view. The progress view is just for displaying not for storing.

This is a fundamental MVC pattern - the view should not be the data store.

Comment: Though the view should not be the datasource, you are allowed to ask for its current state which in this case is provided by the progress property of a UIProgressView.

Comment: You are referring to special cases to facilitate *changing* the view based on certain view properties. If you need to ask your view for a state for your application logic to work, you have a flawed design.